# What is the best way to compare two directories in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, diff

I have two similar directories with slightly different file contents. Is there a good way on Windows to compare the contents of two directories like the Linux diff command?

Comment: Do you need to compare the full contents of similarly named files, or just compare metadata?

Comment: I need to compare full contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BeyondCompare the diff tool to compare the contents of different directories, but you need to install it first.